# Simple ActionListener

Tags: actionlistener

So i'm making a little game in which a player can wander around a map and collect things, but may also come across randomly moving bots. I'm trying to make it so that if the player and standing next to the bot and click's 'fight' the bot loses health.

The only way I can think of doing this is by making an ActionListener in the bot class. So I'm trying to make an 'if' statement like, if the Player is on a nextdoor tile, and clicks 'fight', the bot will lose health. However I've never used an ActionListener and despite looking at lots of examples I still don't understand them.

The bot's coordinates on the map are 'ycord' and 'xcord' and the player is represented by 'P'.

Is there a way of saying this...

```
if(map[ycord+1][xcord].equals("P") && 'fightbutton' is pressed){
                bot.health--;
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use an ActionListener. ActionListeners need to be "registered" on the instance that creates actions, in your case players. So every bot would need to register an ActionListener on every player, which (in my opinion) is a bit messy.

Instead, I would simply create a `hitBy(Player)` method on `Bot` which is executed by some superior `Game` instance. A fighting player would do something like `game.madeHit(this)` and the game searches for close-by bots and then executes `bot.hitBy(player)`. This can be done by simply iterating over a list containing all bots; this list should be available in `Game`.